# A quiz problem on normal distribution and probability?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I was asked this question in interview. I couldnt answer this, can some one help.

An investment, 16% chance to lose money on a quarter, and each quarter follows i.i.d. normal distribution. �Q: what is the probability of losing money by the end of the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is as follows.

`X1, X2, X3, X4 ~ iid N(a,b^2)` (sorry I don't know how to input greek letters.)

and

`P(X1<0) = P[(X1-a)/b < (0-a)/b] = P[Z<(-a/b)] = 0.16`

where `Z` is a standard normal random variable.

By the distribution table of standard normal, we know `-a/b = -0.9944579`

Define `Y = X1 + X2 + X3 + X4`.

Since `X1, X2, X3, X4` are iid, we have`Y ~ N(4a,4b^2) = N[4a, (2b)^2]`.

This problem actually asks you the probability `P(Y<0)`. We can calculate it by

`P(Y<0) = P[(Y-4a)/2b < (0-4a)/2b]`

`= P[Z < 2*(-a/b)] = P[Z < 2*(-0.9944579)]`

`= 0.02335525 = 2.34%`.